# Asp application time

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

is there a way to set the timing for the web app
like something to add the web config to make the time in the app like GMT +2 although the server local time is different ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any time zone you like.  See [`TimeZoneInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) for converting to and from any time zone you like (even a custom one).  Just be sure you don't accidentally use the standard `DateTime.ToLocalTime()` and `DateTime.ToUniversalTime()`, because those will always use the local server time and UTC, respectively.